# How to open a alertDialog on click of the button in the row of a recyclerView in android?

Tags: android

I have a recylerView in which each row has a button I want to open a customized alert view on the click of respective button

Answer (score 0):

When initializing your button give him a tag.
Create an onClickListener where you can switch by tag.